# Why Commands are taken from ViewModel Class?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've just finished watching "[Practical MVVM by Joel Cochran](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BClf7GZR0DQ)" video explaining MVVM, and i didn't understand a key problem.

In the video Joel explaining that the View is unaware of the ViewModel, but still the button is bound to a command within the ViewModel, so every time the button get pressed, the command action is performed.

My question is how the View is unaware of the ViewModel if I need to specifically bind the button to the ViewModel command like:

```
private ICommand _searchByNameCommand;
        public ICommand SearchByNameCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_searchByNameCommand == null)
                {
                    _searchByNameCommand = new RelayCommand(
                            p => this.LoadRealEstateCollectionByName(),
                            p => { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SearchOwnerName); }
                        );
                }
                return _searchByNameCommand;
            }
        }
```

And in the xaml:

```
<Button Content="Search"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding SearchByNameCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

SearchByNameCommand is defined in the ModelView.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around - the ViewModel is unaware of the View?

Comment: `the View is unaware of the ViewModel` - That's just plain wrong and false. If that were true, `{Binding}` wouldn't be possible. Return that book to the store and demand your money back.

Comment: In he's presentation, he claims that the View is (technically) unaware of the ViewModel and the ViewModel is unaware of the View.  He says that they are unaware of each other but they are connected. As strange as it sounds.

Comment: You could say that views are 'late-bound' to view-models, and that they bind to a certain 'interface' (you specify what properties to bind to, not what concrete type the view-model should have). But a view does make assumptions about its data-context and it does need to extract values, so it's not unaware of its view-model. A view-model however does not need to know about what view is observing it, or if it's being observed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is the following:**

Using MVVM, a view is tightly coupled to a view-model via it's DataContext.
The reason why the view is tightly coupled to its view-model is because the view must specify the specific names of observable properties and commands that are contained within its DataContext. That function alone introduces tight coupling.

**RANT:**

I'm not sure if I agree with a view being completely ignorant of its view-model dependency.

Think about it. A view is bound to the state and operations of its data context (aka view-model). In other words, it is tightly coupled to the state of the view-model but not the view-model its self?

What's the point?

So how useful is it to hide the view-model from the view if the view relies completely on its Data Context (i.e. the observable state and the exposed commands of the view-model)?

Comment: Thanks Scott, so what is the proper relationship between the components? Let say i want to create a View that later on in the future, will be easily changed. Should it know the ViewModel and needs to be created with a knowledge of the ViewModel?

Comment: I would say yes. Or else what is the point of databinding if you do not know what properties your binding to. An alternative would be to implement a messaging system where your views and view-models react to messages without knowing the publishers of that message. Here's a post I wrote that describes it: https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/decoupled-event-management/

Comment: Thank you. I can't mark your comment as answered. If you write it as an answer I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you somewhat misunderstood what "being unaware" actually means in this context. In winforms programming, when you had a button and wanted to subscribe to the click event, you had to attach an event handler, for instance

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click);
```

As you can see, that's the tight coupling. You're coupling specific instances together.

With commands in WPF however, there's a pretty big difference, because you don't say `this instance handles this`. You're saying `I have these methods and properties` (ViewModel) and `I need these things to work properly` (View). You can swap instances as you like, as long as they provide the things needed for proper functioning of the view. BUT, you don't care about attaching/detaching handlers, setting manually text values etc. That's all taken care by binding that happens automatically for you. Your View doesn't really know about the specific instance. All it knows is what data and actions it works with. ViewModel doesn't really care either how those data are displayed or dealt with.

That's why I don't actually agree with Scott Nimrod's answer. This is not tight coupling, but rather loose coupling (at least in my opinion). Tight coupling would be when you couldn't change one without affecting the other and that's obviously false in MVVM. That's the point actually, to have things coupled as least as possible. If you want to see tightly coupled components, look at winforms.

Comment: You're right about the loose coupling, but still i accepted Scott answer because he explained that the view does know about the ViewModel even if it's loosely. So basically, i guess the answer is that he knows about A ViewModel, that needs to handle its needs (commands, binding events, etc.) but is unaware of how it is performed. That way when in the future i'll want to replace the view or support more views i could do that quite easily.